# Is there a way to uniquely identify a socket?

Tags: java, oracle, sockets

I'm trying to implement a simple Client/Server program in Java (mainly through the multi [Client](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockClient.java) and [Server](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KKMultiServer.java) tutorials provided by Oracle).

I'm just wondering if there's a way to uniquely identify a connected client on the server side?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, by the value of the `Socket` reference itself.

When a client connects to the server, store the `Socket` instance.
Then you can use it later to identify the connected client.

Comment: Es written, I suggest creating a socket handler class for this. You may even create an own socket class extending your socket and create your own identifier in it if you need it

Comment: Thanks, no idea why I didn't think of this.

Comment: This works like a charm because a socket connection tends to stay open. Consider also how it is done in HTTP where connections are generally on a per-request basis; thus you get potentially dozens of unique socket connections from the same client. To identify a client then you need to be able to transmit an identifier somehow; in for example a Java web environment the server (by default) sets a cookie with an ID which the client will communicate back with each connection it makes.

Comment: Just wished to know if Socket instance will be same or different for all the users behind a proxy server?